# Bash sleep exit early than specified with m or h key in OSX

Tags: macos, bash

I have a script that needs to sleep for certain amount of minutes.
I am running it in OSX.
So the interesting thing I've observed is that 
sleep 5m will finish in less than 20 seconds.
sleep 300 will honor the sleep for 5 minutes as I wanted.
Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `m` suffix is a GNU feature.

It's not supported by POSIX, and not by OS X, FreeBSD or most other `sleep` implementations.

Comment: I've also had something like this (immediate exit with `sleep 5m`) on Ubuntu 16.04 with a script run using `/bin/sh` (which is the [dash shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash:_Ubuntu.2C_Debian_and_POSIX_compliance_of_Linux_distributions) not bash on Ubuntu and Debian).  This is presumably because the "5m" syntax isn't supported by the dash shell.